# start Faye server on system start

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, init

i want to run Faye server on system startup

i'm trying with this in

```
 /etc/init/faye.conf

description "faye"
author      "email@gmail.com"

description "Chat Server for In-house chat rooms"

start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]
stop on run level [!2345]

cd /var/App

exec /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/rackup /var/App/faye.ru -s thin -E production
```

but it not working.
when i'm excuting command

```
 sh faye.conf
```

then working fine.
and even working via irb console

```
  `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/rackup /var/App/faye.ru -s thin -E production -D`
```

any idea where is problem why init script not working self ?

after some investigation i found error:

```
  /usr/bin/env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Do you want to make a startup shell? Use /etc/rc.local.

Comment: You can try move command in `script; end script` block. And try run via `sudo initctl start faye`